# have to Change click event mouse in mouse out event

Tags: javascript, jquery

With below script written for click event.
 I want to use Same code(selectors) for Mouse in, mouse out event

```
 $('.tools_collapsed').wrap('<div class="newparent" />');
    var speed = 600;
    $('.tools_collapsed').show().css({ right: '-250px' }).hide();
    $('.tools_collapsed .collapse_btn').hide();
    $('.tools_expand').click(function () {
        $('.tools_collapsed').show().animate({ right: '0' }, { duration: speed });
        $('.tools_collapsed .collapse_btn').show();
    })
    $('a.collapsed').click(function () {
        $('.tools_expand').css({ display: 'none' });
        $('.tools_collapsed').animate({ right: '-250', easing: 'easeOutQuad' }, 400, function () {
            $('.tools_collapsed .collapse_btn').css("display", "none");
            $('.tools_expand').show("normal");
        });
    })

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: mouse over and mouse out event

Comment: can u plz change events in this script
click event to mouseover and mouse out

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. Show us what you've tried and where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach...

```
function yourFunction(){
   //your code here
}

$("#yourSelector").hover(
    yourFunction(), 
    yourFunction()
);
```

Comment: Unless `yourFunction` *returns* a function, this is incorrect. You have to pass functions to `.hover()`. You are calling the functions instead.

Comment: I agree with this approach over all but the syntax above is wrong as pointed out by @FelixKling .  `$("#yourSelector").hover( yourFunction,  yourFunction);` .  No `()` needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.tools_collapsed').wrap('<div class="newparent" />');
var speed = 600;
$('.tools_collapsed').show().css({ right: '-250px' }).hide();
$('.tools_collapsed .collapse_btn').hide();

$('.tools_expand').on( "mouseenter",function () {
    $('.tools_collapsed').show().animate({ right: '0' }, { duration: speed });
    $('.tools_collapsed .collapse_btn').show();
})

$('.tools_expand').on( "mouseout", function () {      // changed from "a.collapsed"
    $('.tools_expand').css({ display: 'none' });
    $('.tools_collapsed').animate({ right: '-250', easing: 'easeOutQuad' }, 400, function () {
        $('.tools_collapsed .collapse_btn').css("display", "none");
        $('.tools_expand').show("normal");
    });
})
```

Comment: Hi Amar its working fine, but second time when I mouse enter on panel it's automatically coming out and in.
and i have did some changes here...


   $('.tools_expand').hover(function () {
        $('.tools_collapsed').show().animate({ right: '0' }, { duration: speed });
        $('.tools_collapsed .collapse_btn').show();
    })

Comment: HTML:
 <aside class="tools_collapsed" style="display: none;">
            <div class="collapse_btn">
                <a href="#" class="collapsed"></a>
            </div>
</aside>